# MySQL 5.6.10 Safe?

Tags: mysql

Is it safe to upgrade MySQL version from 5.5.29 to 5.6.10 ?

If yes can I know the steps ? I want to upgrade it on my Windows Development Server and CentOS 5.8 too.

I tried to upgrade on CentOS once, my PHP stopped working. Is it necessary to rebuild my PHP too ?

Comment: it's a pretty vague question; you have to do your own QA and test things thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any major update of a critical part of your infrastructure: upgrade your development environment first, run your tests, do some benchmarks. If you think it's ok for you, upgrade production.

That said, we've been running 5.6 since before GA on some high performance/high update throughput systems. It performs a lot better than 5.5 and all the nasty bugs and crashers we found have been solved before 5.6.10. I consider 5.6 safe to update to.